# after multiple times trying but the total doesnot display

Tags: php, mysql, web

I cant find the error will yoou help me out whats issue with this

```
<tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php
                $total = '';
                $s = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amount) as amount FROM tborderdetail 
                WHERE order_id = '$id' ")) ;
                $total = $s -> amount;


                ?>
                 Today :  <?= $total ?>  $
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tfoot>
```

Comment: While this won't fix your problem, please note the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: if i wanna to fix this while using old way than what the way ? and i'm newbie so i hve not much knowledge , so help me guide me , what to do and how ... ! Thanks

Comment: Don't try to fix it under MySQL. Switch to either MySQLi or PDO, or you'll have bigger problems than you're having now. You probably copied this from an outdated tutorial - I'd recommend finding a better tutorial. I'd recommend checking out W3Schools for the [**basics on MySQLi**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp) :)

Comment: can you give oone favour , write this code in mysqli ?

Comment: No. StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). The problem appears to be in your database connection anyway, which you haven't provided info on. Please showcase your relevant table and connection info in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)